# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: heroku migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to deploy a demo app to Heroku. I initially created a model called "posts" to learn how to create a CRUD app. However i decided to scrap posts and use another model called "investments" now that i've deployed it, i'm trying to rake db:migrate, however i'm getting the following error/s

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "image_file_name" character varying

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
```

I've tried deleting the entire posts model, restarting the server and resetting the database, none of these are seeming to get past this one error.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error backtrace?

Comment: -- add_attachment(:posts, :image)
D, [2018-02-20T06:53:05.328038 #4] DEBUG -- :    (9.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "image_file_name" character varying
D, [2018-02-20T06:53:05.333537 #4] DEBUG -- :    (5.0ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2018-02-20T06:53:05.337156 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.5ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(5274046015852070415)
rake aborted!

Comment: Is it possible that you edited a migration that already ran on heroku? Doing this would confuse rails during future migrations.

Comment: It's most certainly possible. I'm still a beginner :/